# charset=utf-8 - but it cannot display "ü"

Tags: html

I declared the charset like all current HTML5 websites, but now German letters cannot be displayed anymore. If I leave the declaration out it works again. I think one should have that declaration. What is wrong?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="de">
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html,charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>äää</title>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


 </head>
 <body>
        üüü ääää öööö
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: You may be telling the browser that the page is utf-8, but if you edited the document under some OTHER charset, then you will get trashed outputs.

Comment: You're using HTML5 so `<meta charset="utf-8">` will do just fine.

Comment: @MarcB how can I fix the problem?

Comment: @Vucko - It's worth noting that if one uses `<meta charset="utf-8">`, then (according the [W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#html5charset)) the entire meta element must fit in the first 1024 bytes of the document.

Comment: @TedHopp I was just pointing that he can use the shorter HTML5 declaration. And his original declaration is in those first 1024 bytes of document so the HTML5 declaration would also work. You should put that also in your answer, its very useful.

Comment: @Vucko - Yes, I thought you made a good point about using the `meta charset` tag with HTML5. I was just adding a bit of additional (and arcane) information that I thought worth mentioning.

Comment: The code is not correct; the tag needs to have a semicolon, not a comma. It is impossible to say whether this or something else was the real problem; no testable valid code was presented.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `charset` parameter needs to be separated from the MIME type by a semicolon, not a comma. See [the W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset).

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: @user2952265 - Are you sure that the HTML file is actually encoded with UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

you have insert `,` instead of `;` between charset and text/html
try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your html file is saved in UTF-8 and if you use HTML5 declaration your meta can look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="de">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
.
.
.
</head>
```